# How do I lookup which class implements a method in Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Newbie here, going through *"Pharo by Example"*. The book mentions an example of `EllipseMorph new openInWorld` result in a call to `Morph openInWorld`, while `EllipseMorph defaultColor` is an overridden message: how do I figure this out using the System Browser or something else?

The usual *find method* way only finds matches in the immediately selected class. Is it possible in general to lookup which class will respond to (say) `Foo bar`?

*Update*:
Thanks for all the suggestions (Finder, Spotter); the Debugger is the most eye-opening of the tools I've encountered yet!

Comment: I don't completely understand your method, but you can select a method name and press cmd+m (or ctrl+m on windows) and it will show you all implementors displayed as a tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smalltalk offers lots of tools and browsers that can help you with this. If you already know the name of the message, you can:

- use spotter (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) to type it in and see all senders and implementers, and select one to browse it.
- while looking at a method in a browser, click on the small green up/down triangles to the left of the method name indicating implementations up and/or down the hierarchy, respectively, to open a browser on them.
- select the name of the message (nearly) anywhere and type <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to see the i**m**plementors and <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to see the se**n**ders.

In this case you could also type `EllipseMorph new openInWorld` in a playground and select *Debug-It* from the menu. That will open a debugger with the selection on `new`. If you click on *into*, the top line changes to `EllipseMorph class(Behavior) new`. That indicates that the `new` from `Behavior` is used here. If you continue stepping with *into* (2 times), you'll see it change to `EllipseMorph(BorderedMorph) initialize`. By just following the trace of messages sent, you can see where everything is implemented.

Answer (score 5):

To add to Stephan's answer (+1), one of the easiest ways, especially if you're new to Smalltalk and prefer using the GUI, is to use the Finder tool. Just left-click anywhere on the background (the equivalent of your desktop in your Pharo image) and select `Tools > Finder`:

[image: Opening the Finder tool in Pharo]

Next, type the name of the method, e.g. `openInWorld` in the search field (make sure "Selectors" is selected in the drop-down to the right) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image: Using the Finder tool in Pharo]

You can then browse all methods containing your search string (notice it's automatically a wildcard search) and the classes implementing them. The panel at the bottom shows you selected implementations, and the context menu gives you a few more options, e.g. browsing the class you selected.